# using webcam & taking high res (2Mpix) pictures in a web application

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, image, image-processing

I need a web based application where the user needs to fill in 3 fields and taking a high resolution image (2mpix) with a webcam. Once these are ready I need to post them to the server so they are saved in a database.

1) What is the best way/tools available?
2) I saw this[jquery webcam plugin](http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/)  -  is it possible to capture photos through your webcam up to 1920×1080?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The quality of the pictures you take with ANY camera depends on the sophistication of the camera.
Cameras have maximum resolutions and settings to configure them to a lower one as needed.

If the webcam on the machine has a resolution as high as the one you need, you'll probably be able to do this.

And its worth mentioning that the **jquery webcam plugin** requires flash to be available on the machine.

Since you've tagged this question with the ".net" and "c#" tags i guess i should mention that you can access the webcam via a **silverlight** app as well.